# Oracle SQL - not returning records if any one of them meets NE criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

Each entity in the DB has 10s of records created for it throughout the entity's life. I'm in the situation where I want to exclude all records for a particular entity if any one of the DB records for it has a year of '2017', and I'm not sure, and can't find an explanation of, how.

E.g. lets say I have two entities: 'Example 1' and 'Example 2'.

Table:

```
+ --- + --------- + --- + ---- +
| Row | ID        | UID | Year |
+ --- + --------- + --- + ---- +
| 1   | Example 1 | 001 | 2017 |
| 2   | Example 1 | 002 | 2016 |
| 3   | Example 1 | 003 | 2016 |
| 4   | Example 1 | 004 | 2014 |
| 5   | Example 2 | 005 | 2016 |
| 6   | Example 2 | 006 | 2015 |
| 7   | Example 2 | 007 | 2014 |
+ --- + --------- + --- + ---- +
```

Based on this example, the output I'm looking for from my query is one column/row:

Output:

`ID
Example 2`

As 'Example 1' has a record in row 1 with a year of 2017, any record for example 1 would be excluded.

I'm partially familiar with `DISTINCT`, but I *think* this function would just give me a unique value from any of the records that do match the criteria of my query.

e.g. `select DISTINCT ID from table where year!='2017'`
would return one record for Example 1 because the records for it in row 2-4 don't have a year of 2017.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a quite self-explanatory way:

```
select distinct ID_col
from yourTable t1
where not exists ( select 1
                   from yourTable t2
                   where t1.ID_col = t2.ID_col
                     and t2.year_col = 2017
                 )
```

Here you extract all the rows for which does `not exist` a row with the same `ID` and `year = 2017`; the `DISTINCT` is used to get one row per value.

Notice that I used different names for the columns, because in your example you use reserved words, which can be dangerous.

Comment: As the answer says, this is most self-explanatory, or most clear on it's own of the valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption on that example query is correct.

You can achive what you want in a few different ways, one of them being

```
select  distinct ID
from    table
where   ID not in (select distinct ID from table where year = '2017')
```

Another way, overcomplicated but interesting if you want to explore more SQL features, could be

```
select  distinct ID
from    table t1
left join
        (
          select  distinct ID
          from    table
          where   year = '2017'
        ) t2
on      t1.ID = t2.ID
where   t2.ID is null
```

The `left join` will preserve all the rows on the left table, giving `NULL` values on the right table's columns if they don't join.
In this case, all the IDs that don't have rows with 2017 wouldn't join, hence filtering  `t2.ID is null` would give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

One way is with `GROUP BY` and a conditional count in `HAVING`. Test against other solutions to see which is most efficient for your data.

```
select   id
from     your_table
group by id
having   count(case when yr = 2017 then 1 end) = 0
;
```

(I changed the column name `year` to `yr` and you should do so too, `year` is an Oracle keyword and even if it is not currently reserved, it may become so in the future - at which point you may be in big pain.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a subquery filter

```
select distinct ID
    from myTable
    where ID not in (
        select ID
            from myTable
            where year = '2017'
    )
```